# How to completely remove an apt package, so that its first install scripts will run again

Tags: apt

Some packages have interactive package configuration scripts that only run on first install. Is there a way to manually trigger this, or cause apt to forget that it was installed? `apt remove` doesn't seem to do this.

Comment: I don't know apt that well but seems to be related to `DEBIAN_FRONTEND` with some googling but maybe you want to it to be always 'interactive'. Does `apt` have a switch to cleanup old cache or old app config answers, etc. Check out how this question logic uses dpkg params and such with apt remove: https://askubuntu.com/questions/972516/debian-frontend-environment-variable. Maybe on install you tell it to purge all including saved configs. Otherwise, maybe a simple reboot could help still as I was curious if you've already rebooted before reinstall but after uninstall. Quick research thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge “package-name”
```

this will remove everything, even local config and data, and run installation steps next time `apt install` is ran.

To re-run without deleting everything, this also worked for me:

```
dpkg-reconfigure -plow “package-name”
```

Comment: Where did you find your source? If it was Pimp Juice IT, let us all know. He should get some credit if his link was helpful, thanks quinn.

Comment: @vssher thats not where i found it. it was after googling a bunch and trying different things. I found the two examples here (the one for reinstall and the one without) in two different places. I don't remember where specifically though.